# Undefined reference to f_ and fprime_

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

```
program main
implicit none
double precision p, a, b, tol
a = 1.0d0
b = 30.0d0
tol = 1e-8
call newtonbisection(p, a, b, tol)

contains

function f(x)
implicit none
double precision x,f
f = SIN(X) - exp(-x)
end function

function fprime(x)
implicit none
double precision fprime, x
fprime = COS(x) + exp(-x)
end function

subroutine newtonbisection(p, a, b, tol)
implicit none
double precision p, a, b, tol
double precision f, fprime
double precision fb, fp, fp2

a = 1.0d0
b = 30.0d0

p = a

do
fb = f(b)
fp = f(p)
fp2 = fprime(p)

p = p - (fp/fp2)

if (p < a .or. p > b) then
    p = (a+b) / 2.d0
end if

if (fp*fb < 0) then
    a = p
else
    b = p
end if
print*, "a, b, p, fp", a, b, p, fp

if (dabs(fp) < tol) then
   exit
end if

end do

end subroutine

end program
```

when I compile (gfortran newtonbisection.f90) I'm getting following errors:

```
newtonbisection.f90:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to 'f_'

newtonbisection.f90:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to 'f_'

newtonbisection.f90:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to 'fprime_'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Last time when I was having similar issues, putting implicit none and contains fixed them, but not this time. Why does it say f and fprime are not defined when they are?

Comment: I suggest you to use more indentation in your programs. Your code is hard to read.

Comment: Okay thanks for the suggestion. I will keep that in mind for the next time.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put lines as

```
  double precision f, fprime
```

into subroutine `newtonbisection`. That means that `f` and `fprime` would be external functions, but they are not, they are internal functions of the main program.

Delete that line. It has no place there, the internal functions see the other functions due to the so-called *host association*, they are all contained in a single host program.

Also, internals functions and subroutines don't require repeated `implicit none`, the `implicit none` from the main program is valid in them, because they are contained in it.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you. That's true I don't need that line. After deleting the line, it compiles okay, but now it falls into an infinite loop. I doubt if it's because of the line `if (p < a .or. p > b) then`. I wanted to have a case when p goes out of the bound [a,b]. I've never used "or" in fortran programming before, but from googling this seems to be the right way. Is this correct?

Comment: This is a new problem and warrants a new question. Try to play with the code a bit and if you still have a problem, ask in a new question.

Comment: Okay I will. Thank you.

Comment: I fixed the problem by getting rid of `dabs`. It should just be `fp < tol`. I guess `.OR.` is right way to use logical operators in Fortran

Comment: I don't know, as I said, if you need help with that, ask a new question. BTW, `dabs` is ugly, use just `abs`.